# Select a JSON attribute based on other elements within an array using JSONPath

Tags: arrays, json, json-path-expression

I have a sample JSON array:

```
{
"data": {
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 192,
            "name": "John Black",
            "username": "jblack",
            "email": "jblack@myorganization.com",
            "extern_uid": "user distinguished name"
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "username": "jadoe",
            "email": "jadoe@myorganization.com",
            "extern_uid": "user distinguished name"
        }
    ]
}}
```

I want to extract an attribute based on another attribute using JSONPath expression,

For example:

I want to search for the name "Jane Doe" and extract values from the Jane Doe array like **id: 63** or any other value in the Jane Doe array.  Is this possible in JSONPath? I am not an expert in JSONPath so I apologize if this may seem trivial for others

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

found the solution:

$.data.list[?(@.username == "jblack")].id

Will return:

"id": 192